# How to access jasper reports properties from a report to specify ROOT_DIR location on each developer machine?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a report where I define ROOT_DIR as a parameter.  I pass this in when I render the reports in my servlet.

Something like this:

```
 <parameter name="ROOT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/Some/Path/To/Reports"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="IMAGES_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROOT_DIR}+"/images"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
<parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$P{ROOT_DIR}+"/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

My issue is that we now have more developers working on the reports, so I would like to find a way to not have everyone changing the defaultValueExpression on ROOT_DIR with each commit to their git workspace / home directory.

I was thinking that we could use a property in iReport (Preferences -> iReport -> Jasper Report Properties Tab), but I can't seem to find a way to reference those values from the defaultValueExpression?

Is there any way to access these properties from within a report? Or another suggestions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with help of resource bundles.

You can create resource file and then use "variables" with help of ***`$R{}`*** syntax.

#### The sample

The folder structure is:

```
reports
    images
        Number1.png
```

The properties file (*folders.properties*):

```
ROOT_DIR=/reports
```

The name of *resource file* is set with help of report's attribute ***resourceBundle***.

In my sample I've set attribute like this: **`resourceBundle="folders"`**.

You can do it, for example in *iReport*:

[image]

The *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report33" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="folders" uuid="6c23de18-90a0-4246-85ab-1a6fae930bd4">
    <parameter name="IMAGES_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[$R{ROOT_DIR}+"/images"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="88" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RealSize">
                <reportElement uuid="7745c4a6-ce7e-4fd8-aae9-4752488dd038" x="325" y="19" width="64" height="56"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{IMAGES_DIR} + "/Number1.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The report's design in *iReport*:

[image]

The result will be (via preview in *iReport*):

[image]

Every member from your developer team can change path (set by **ROOT_DIR** key) in properties file and this solution will work without using *Java* code and templates recompiling.

---

**Notes**:

1. The *properties* file should be in classpath.
2. Information about [Internationalized Report Templates](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n).

Comment: The file should be called folders.properties? and be located along side the .jrxml file?

Comment: I've added info to the answer

Comment: the **"Resource Bundle" must be set on the dataset, e.g. `report -> Misc -> Main Dataset -> Resource Bundle`**. had to search for it in Jasper Report Studio (Eclipse).